# One less data is deleted when using hash table delete function

Tags: c++

I have created a project using a hash table with separate chaining. Now for my delete function, there is a slight problem, sometimes when a try to delete a node it always deletes 1 less node than it's supposed to. To simplify what I mean is, for example, if I am trying to delete all "people" objects that are in Columbia then I expect 56 data to be deleted but only 55 get deleted. And when I try to delete again then it realizes there is 1 left and deletes that. So every time it is deleting one less data than it is supposed to. Please let me know if there is a problem with my implementation.

```
void HashMap::deleteByString(string toDelete)
{
    bool haveDeleted = false;
    int totalDeleted = 0;

    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets; i++) {
        Node* current = hashTable[i];
        Node* previous = NULL;
        while (current && current->data.getCountry() != toDelete) {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        if (current) {
            if (previous) {
                previous->next = current->next;
                haveDeleted = true;
                delete current;
                ++totalDeleted;
            }
            else {
                hashTable[i] = current->next;
                haveDeleted = true;
                delete current;
                ++totalDeleted;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will only delete one item per bucket. What happens if you have 2 items that you want to delete in the same bucket?

Comment: This is not a [mcve], and it will take a lot of effort to get this to compile and run on my machine... possibly the bug is not in this code but is in the code not provided, and my other code may not have that bug, making it hard to reproduce.  Help us help you.

Comment: Sorry about that @Elijay, I'll make sure to include all the relevant classes next time.

Comment: Thank you @MikeVine I believe that is the problem as well, I will look into it.

Comment: @MalikSafwan _"I'll make sure to include all the relevant classes next time."_ Why not starting with [edit]Ing and improving this one??

Comment: Worth your time to fix this one @MalikSafwan . Your question history is mostly poorly received questions with a score of 0 or less. You're coming close to earning a question ban and those are extremely hard to dig out from. It can literally take years. Deleting questions doesn't help, only improving questions and asking new, high quality questions can tip the scales in your favour, and if you can't ask new questions...

Comment: @user4581301 Yes you are right, I will make sure to improve my existing questions and to also make sure I ask questions in a proper way for the future.  Is there any tip you can give me, seeing as that you have probably visited all my questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `deleteByString` iterates over all content without using a hash function on its argument, we can assume that countries are not the hash key and thus there can be arbitrarily many items with the same country in a bucket. You can't just drop out of your inner loop when you find one of them in this case.

Something like the following should be what you want:

```
void deleteByString(std::string toDelete)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets; i++) {
        Node* current = hashTable[i];
        Node* previous = NULL;
        while (current) {
            if ( current->data.getCountry() != toDelete) {
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
            } else {
                if (previous) {
                    previous->next = current->next;
                    auto temp = current;
                    current = previous->next;
                    delete temp;
                } else {
                    hashTable[i] = current->next;
                    auto temp = current;
                    current = hashTable[i];
                    delete temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically since iteration is continuing after a deletion, you now need to make sure `previous` and `current` are correctly maintained across deletions.

Comment: Thank you it seems that you were able to grasp exactly what I meant my code to do.